# "SHK.h" file not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sharekit

Sorry guys for noob question, need help.
I'm try to use Sharekit - https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit.

I'm doing all steps from "Installing sharekit" wiki page, and I have no errors before I trying to import SHK.h.
SHK.h visible in autocomplete, but I've got error.
What could be missed?

Comment: Sorry, there was my mistake, I placed Sharekit on one level up than my project was placed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer in the link https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/issues/393#issuecomment-6057929 is partially exact. You can have ShareKit folder at the same level of your project.

Just add in your project "Header Search Paths" (assuming that the directory where you put ShareKit is called "ShareKit" :

```
$(SRCROOT)/../ShareKit/Classes/**
```

And

```
$(SRCROOT)/../ShareKit/Submodules/**
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have the problem but you can try

Click on project -> select your target -> Build phases -> expand compile sources and make sure that you have your SHK.m file there if not then add it.

Comment: Hi Mert, I trying to use your advise, when I add SHK.m to "compile sources" it's icon placeholder was empty and filename marked with red color. SHK.m file seems to be found but all files included there also have same problem. I think that trying to add file by file all sharekit library is not the right way.

Comment: You can remove all the red marked files from you project and drag them from finder to your project. When asked to copy or reference your files, copy them, unless they are not already in your projects folder. Red color means you have the files in your project as reference but the can not found on your file system. You need to be careful about adding them with sub directories. If you choose create folder references then you need to type directory names while importing files like "directoryName/filename.h". However do not choose create folder references unless you need it.

Comment: Sorry, there was my mistake, I placed Sharekit on one level up than my project was placed...